# All nearest smaller values

Tags: c++, stack

i want to construct my  code for solving All nearest smaller values problem,here is my effort for this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
void all_smallest(int a[],int n)
{
    stack<int>s;
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        while(!s.empty() && s.top()>=a[x])
        {
            cout<<s.top();
            s.pop();
        }
        if(s.empty()){ continue;}
        else
        {
            s.push(a[x]);
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    all_smallest(a,n);

    return 0;
}
```

it compiles,but no output  ,why?please help me

Comment: Your all_smallest function will do nothing because the line that contains continue will be executed always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_nearest_smaller_values) you didn't implement the algorithm correctly.  Here's what it should be:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<stack>
    using namespace std;
    void all_smallest(int a[],int n)
    {
        stack<int>s;
        for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
            while(!s.empty() && s.top()>=a[x])
            {
                s.pop();
            }
            if(!s.empty())
            {
                cout<<s.top();
            }
            s.push(a[x]);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int a[]={0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15};
        int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
        all_smallest(a,n);
        cout << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
    004022601151337
```

Comment: yeah,i was thinking that pop and top should be together for performing pop operation,so i mixed its in each other,thanks for correction

Answer (score 1):

Since s starts out empty, the `else` clause never happens (so s stays empty).

Answer (score 0):

Code (with proper formatting and bug fixes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void all_smallest(int a[], int n) {
  stack<int> s;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    while (!s.empty() and s.top() >= a[i]) {
      s.pop();
    }
    if (!s.empty()) {
      cout << s.top() << ' ';
    } else {
      cout << "- ";
    }
    s.push(a[i]);
  }
}

int main() {
  int a[] = {0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15};
  int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
  all_smallest(a, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 4 0 2 2 6 0 1 1 5 1 3 3 7
```

Comment: Other than some very minor output modifications, how does this code differ *significantly* from that posted over 10 years ago in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178939/10871073)?

Comment: For non-increasing array the original code won't print anything. Also, in cases where the array has values smaller than any previous value, it won't print anything, i.e. smaller output length that the input array length.